# How can I remove 0 shares after withdraw total amount from liquidity pool using stellar laboratory?

Tags: stellar-laboratory

I had tried to withdraw total amount from a pool liquidity using stellar laboratory
BTW, after withdraw, there is 0 shares in wallet as like in below image

How can I clean this 0 shares so that I remove some assets?

Thank you in advance

[image: 0 shares of AQUA/Simpfarm LP]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing here is the existing trustline to the LP. You need to remove the trustline in order to get rid of it with a `changeTrust` [operation](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations#change-trust) and pass it the [pool shares definition](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/issuing-assets/anatomy-of-an-asset#pool-shares) as asset.

An [example XDR](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAgAAAADA0qJsaEfl7cZ%2BdUZm6eXZLbDto0itsggbvyYXHEvPbwAAAGQB%2B4VB1v4C5QAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAABAAAAAMDSomxoR%2BXtxn51Rmbp5dktsO2jSK2yCBu%2FJhccS89vAAAABgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAUFRVUEAAAAAW5QuU6wzyP0KgMx8GxqF19g4qcQZd6rRizrwV%2FjjPfAAAAACU2ltcGZhcm0AAAAAAAAAANOTjaE4TCmvIMcsIRiIK5T7nHDn91UIFUnWQ2INjBnZAAAAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=public) could look like this:

```
AAAAAgAAAADA0qJsaEfl7cZ+dUZm6eXZLbDto0itsggbvyYXHEvPbwAAAGQB+4VB1v4C5QAAA
AEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAABAAAAAMDSomxoR+Xtxn51Rmbp5dktsO2jSK
2yCBu/JhccS89vAAAABgAAAAMAAAAAAAAAAUFRVUEAAAAAW5QuU6wzyP0KgMx8GxqF19g4qcQ
Zd6rRizrwV/jjPfAAAAACU2ltcGZhcm0AAAAAAAAAANOTjaE4TCmvIMcsIRiIK5T7nHDn91UI
FUnWQ2INjBnZAAAAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
```